# How to avoid making multiple connections to postgres database when accessing using R

Tags: sql, r, dbi, rpostgres

I'm using the following code however it is creating multiple connections when calling the map function and they are not closing. As a result my rds database is getting flooded with connections. Is there any way to change this code to prevent so many connections?

```
   connect.to.database <- function (dbname, schema = "public", host, port, user, pass) {
      con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                       dbname = dbname,
                       user = user,
                       password = pass,
                       host = host,
                       port = port)
      
      
      # this puts the schema in the search path, which means that instead of
      # having to use <schema name>.<table name> you can just write <table name>
      res <- dbSendQuery(con, paste0("SET search_path TO ",
                                     dbQuoteIdentifier(con, schema),
                                     ", public"))
      
      # check for errors
      dbFetch(res)
      dbClearResult(res)
      
      con
    }

    schemas <- dbGetQuery(connect.to.database(dbname, "public", host, port, user, password), paste0("SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"))
    
    schema_names <- schemas %>% pull()
    
    schemas_tables <- map(.x = schema_names,~dbGetQuery(connect.to.database(dbname, "public", host, port, user, password), paste0("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ","'",.x,"'")) %>% mutate(schema_name = .x)) %>%
                      bind_rows()
```

Comment: Consider using the `pool` package https://db.rstudio.com/pool/

Comment: You explicitly `dbConnect` but never `dbDisconnect`. Perhaps I'm missing something, but *you are doing it to yourself*. Consider calling `con <- connect.to.database(...)` *outside` of your `map`, and using that `con` inside your `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single global connection object and use *it* within `map`. (I remove the unnecessary `paste0` from your first query.)

```r
conn <- connect.to.database(dbname, "public", host, port, user, password)
schema <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata")

schemas_tables <- map(
  .x = schema$schema_name,
  ~ dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ","'",.x,"'")) %>%
    mutate(schema_name = .x)
) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. While there are security concerns about malicious [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's a single data analyst running the query. Both `DBI` (with `odbc`) and `RODBC` support [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries), either natively or via add-ons.

That would change this to:

```r
schemas_tables <- map(
  .x = schema$schema_name,
  ~ dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ?",
               params = list(.x)) %>%
    mutate(schema_name = .x)
) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

But frankly, I think it might be much easier to use `IN` instead of `=`. Again, using parameter-binding.

```r
schemas_tables <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema IN (?)",
                             params = list(schema$schema_name))
```

(No `map` required.)

Or I believe you can do it in one query, not two.

```r
dbGetQuery(conn, "
    select table_name
    from information_schema.tables
    where table_schema in (
      select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
    )")
```

### Remember

... to close the connection when you are done.

```r
dbDisconnect(conn)
```